# Wordpress homepage not loading and redirects to Host server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am quite new to the area of website development and am having an issue with my website's homepage. I was running Wordpress 3.5.x and yesterday updated to Wordpress 4.7.1. I updated Wordpress manually by deleting all the files/folders (except wp-content, wp-config.php) and replacing them from a fresh download of Wordpress.

And now the homepage for my website does not load. All the other pages are loading fine.

Homepage -> http://isas.hu

Other page -> http://isas.hu/university/the-university/ - This, for example, and all other pages work absolutely fine.

When I try to go to the homepage it redirects to my Host server and gives a message in Hungarian, which translates to: "The website is not uploaded" and "The space is provided by Mediacenter"

I tried replacing the new index.php file with the old one. I also replaced the new template-loader.php (in the wp-includes folder) with the old one but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which theme are you using? I think it is something to do with the theme.

Comment: Accesspress Lite. I tried switching the Theme to Twenty eleven and another one (using the Live Preview feature) but I get the same error for the homepage.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file. This file determines the url rewriting.It should be in the root folder

Comment: I do have the .htaccess file, although I am not sure what exactly I should be changing in it in order to get this working.

This is what it contains:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Sorry, and yes it is in the root folder.

Comment: Your .htaccess file is ok. You may have to check your base,home url. It's available wp_options table of your wordpress database.

Comment: I mean siteurl and home entries in wp_options table in your database

Comment: Both of the entries in the database are correct and point to http://isas.hu/

Comment: just remove/rename the .htaccess file and see what happens.

Comment: Now none of the pages load and the homepage still gives the same error. As for the other pages I get the 

Not Found

The requested URL /from-the-presidents-desk/ was not found on this server.

And adding the .htaccess file restores me to the original situation.

Comment: Just replace a simple index.php file with a echo "helloworld" and see if it correctly displays.

Comment: Thanks for your help MACMAN. This is really embarrassing but there was an additional index.html file hidden in my root directory that was causing the trouble. With my tunnel vision I just did not see it until I tried the echo trick. Now the website works fine. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Good to hear that. I see the website is now displaying correctly.